# Jenkins role based strategy is not reflecting

Tags: jenkins, roles, cloudbees

I would like to manage my users in Jenkins with admin.I m planning to do it by Role based strategy in configure global setting option. But i cant see the option even Cloudbees Role Based Access Control Plugin is installed in my plugin list. 
Any suggestions?

Note: As I am in a env where no internet access,  it is very difficult to re install the plugin and try again.

Thanks 
Jeevan

Comment: Try removing the Cloudbees RBAC plugin.

Answer (score 5):

I found where the option is to enable **Role-based Authorization Strategy** plugin after installing the plugin manually.

Checked the plugin is installed already.
[image: verify plugin is installed]

Step-1: Go to **Manage Jenkins** from your admin dashboard.
[image: Go to Manage Jenkins]

Step-2: Select **Configure Global Security**
[image: Select Configure Global Security]

Step-3: Under Authorization there will be an option at the bottom like this to select **Role-Based Strategy** (select that option & Apply & Save)
[image: select role based strategy under authorization strategy]

you should see **Manage and Assign Roles** button now.
[image: Manage and Assign Roles]

select on **Manage and Assign Roles** and you can see following options to manage users, roles, and strategy based on your requirement.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to activate **Role-Based Strategy**.

Go to **Manage Jenkins > Configure System** screen, then check **Enable security** and choose **Role-Based Strategy** in Authorization section:[image]

Then you will be available to define and assign roles by using the **Manages Roles** item which appears in the **Manage Jenkins** screen.

Of course, if you cannot do all of that, then you just don't have enough privileges.

See the official [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) for more details.

Comment: i am logged in with admin

Comment: Then try to configure as I wrote above.

Comment: Biruk: i think u didnt go through my question thoroughly.i am a admin n installed role strategy plugin but i m nt able to see option role-strategy in autherization

Comment: worked for me, thanks.
Jenkins for windows version 2.249.1, OS: windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I too had faced the same problem. Jenkins **doesn't** come with the Role-Based Strategy plugin by default. We have to install this plugin as per our requirements. Sorry, but for installation, you have to go online, because this plugin requires installation from the web.

After connection, just go to *'Manage Plugins'*.

-> Under *'Available'*, search for **"role-based"**.

-> Now you can see the *'Role-Based Authorization Strategy'* plugin, which you can select and then easily install.

I recommend, if no build job is running, you should select the *'Download now and install after restart'* options, so that the plugin starts working perfectly right after restarting.

Now, go to *'Configure Global Security'*.

-> there you can see now *'Role-Based Strategy'* under Authorization which you have to select for enabling Role-based strategy on users.